# react-redux performance re-render components

Tags: performance, react-native, react-redux, react-native-router-flux

I'm having performance issues with my react-native application, I've encountered the problem but I do not know what the best way to solve it, I'll describe below my scenario:

I have a navigation for 3 scenes:

```
Scene 1 ==> Scene 2 ==> Scene 3
```

Scene 2 has an extensive list of items, in Scene 3 I can add or remove items from the Store (I am using the Flux architecture), when this occurs the state of the application is changed and the assembled components are re-rendered, which is The case of Scene 1, Scene 2 and Scene 3, the problem is that the rendering of Scenes 1 and 2 are heavy which causes a very great delay in the acting of Scene 3, after much research I discovered that I can use the method `ShouldComponentUpdate` to handle re-rendering, my question is how do I render only the change that has occurred in my list and not the entire list again, as this implies traversing every array again.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit confused. Are you using Flux or Redux? If you are using react-redux, you can use mapStateToProps to bind your components to part of your Redux store. The components should then only re-render when those props change.

Edit: You may also consider making a new React component for the list items. Each item would then only re-render when their individual props change.

[Redux Usage with React](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html#implementing-container-components)

Comment: I'm using react-redux lib, and I do mapStateToProps but the performance not be a better, this problem just occorred when I add item in array , when I remove or edit item the performance is good.

Comment: Could you post your Scene component jsx?